# CakePHP - Capturing and using debugging error messages

Tags: cakephp

I am working on testing with Klarna Checkout (a payments system) for my CakePHP app.

Basically Klarna servers makes certain PUSH requests to a URL on my site at which I save the purchase information. But since it Klarna servers that make this request and it is made only once, I have a hard time debugging this request since I can't see the error output since I am not triggering the request. My idea is to send an email to myself with the errors when these PUSH requests come, but now to my question.

In CakePHP, how can I capture the error dump you normally see when the debug is turned on in a variable and send it to my email? Is there a variable loaded with the errors? And if my code fails, I can't really send an email to myself anymore ... problematic.

Comment: Logging is a great tool for this. CakeLog::write() to capture all your debug information into a file for later observation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How come people are only commenting the answer these days and not actually writing answers?

Comment: I would have to write a more verbose version of it - and didnt feel like it at the time ;) maybe someone else wants to earn some points, though.